# How can we convert integer to sha384? Can Anybody help me out in it?

Tags: javascript, c#

How can we convert an integer to sha384 hash, I am trying it in JavaScript and C# both, in both I get different answers.
In C#, From following program, I get this answer:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var InputBytes = 2;
            using (SHA384 sha384Hash = SHA384.Create())
            {
                //From String to byte array
                byte[] sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InputBytes.ToString());
                byte[] hashBytes = sha384Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
                
                // replacing - with empty
                string hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty);
                
                // final output
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The SHA384 hash of {0} is: {1}",InputBytes, hash.ToLower()));
            }
    }
}
```

Answer:

```
The SHA384 hash of 2 is: d063457705d66d6f016e4cdd747db3af8d70ebfd36badd63de6c8ca4a9d8bfb5d874e7fbd750aa804dcaddae7eeef51e
```

But is JavaScript, I am getting this answer from crypto JavaScript library:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA384(2).toString();
console.log(hash);
1402e01a160a97a99698ba6657b0feeef3d663056e532cbc19fe8e1b37076dd12193a48528b07adaadfe0d0991847f10
```

Comment: The C# result is the hash of the string value "2". I expect CryptoJS might be using a binary representation of 2.

Comment: What is the solution then @Llama ?

Comment: `var hash = CryptoJS.SHA384("2").toString();`

Comment: Clearly the solution is to input data into the SHA384 algorithm in the format it expects. For that you'll have to find out how CryptoJS represents numeric value 2 before passing it into its internal implementation of the SHA384 algorithm.

Comment: Or if you are able to change the JS code, use derpirscher's suggestion. My assumption is that you can't change it, or else you would presumably have used string there too.

Comment: @Llama my assumption is more, that C# complained about a syntax error and expected a string, but JS didn't complain and just interpreted the `2` in whatever way ...

Comment: Exactly, what @derpirscher said

Comment: Does anyone can help me in its solution?

Comment: Several people have recommended `CryptoJS.SHA384("2")`, Have you tried this and what was the result? The C# is hashing `"2"`.

Comment: I have used CryptoJS.SHA384(2) which result is 1402e01a160a97a99698ba6657b0feeef3d663056e532cbc19fe8e1b37076dd12193a48528b07adaadfe0d0991847f10 , Actually I want this accurate result for 2 number in C# for my project. When I'm applying CryptoJS.SHA384("2"), C3 and JS both giving same answers.

Comment: I want same answers in JS and C# for integer 2.

Comment: In your C# version you have `InputBytes.ToString()` which will give you the hash of `"2"` no matter the type of `InputBytes`.

Comment: The problem is in your C# code!

Comment: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() don't accept integers

Comment: Do you have any solution @peter ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232140/discussion-between-muhammad-ehsan-shaikh-and-peter-smith).

Answer (score 0):

From the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232140/discussion-between-muhammad-ehsan-shaikh-and-peter-smith) it's clear that the OP wants to hash value of 2 and not the string "2".

For that C# could look like this:

```
var InputBytes = 2;
using (SHA384 sha384Hash = SHA384.Create())
{
    byte[] hashBytes = sha384Hash.ComputeHash(BitConverter.GetBytes(InputBytes));
    string hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The SHA384 hash of {0} is: {1}", InputBytes, hash.ToLower()));
}
```

The above code will produce the following hash:

> `17a600ee898f4277197faf6abd18e8ec7539a6ac4a54bb7b9bf14be194e17025749a4b8d4dfda6cd2efcfac0c5179415`

But also, the JS code is invalid as CryptoJS as an input takes [string or WordArray](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/971c31f0c931f913d22a76ed488d9216ac04e306/src/sha384.js#L35) which is an array of 32bit values, with information how many significant bytes are in the value.

So to hash value of 2 we need to create `WordArray` object:

```
b = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([0x02000000]); //little-endian 32-bit long value of 2
```

and pass that to hash function.

```
CryptoJS.SHA384(b).toString()
```

With that, we will get the same hash (`17a600ee898f4277197faf6abd18e8ec7539a6ac4a54bb7b9bf14be194e17025749a4b8d4dfda6cd2efcfac0c5179415`) produced by CryptoJS as we got from C#.